# scipy Rotation.as_euler and rotation converter produce different results

Tags: python, scipy, rotation, euler-angles

**[www.andre-gaschler.com/rotationconverter](http://www.andre-gaschler.com/rotationconverter)**

**https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CKxr.png
Euler angles in Output section.
**

**Rotation.as_euler**

```
R.from_rotvec([0.246806, -0.816317, -0.220443]).as_euler("xyz", degrees=True)
>> array([ 24.49758771, -43.57370107, -23.37261822])
```

Which one is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're inputting radians on the site but you've got degrees=True in the function call. Try playing around with them.

Comment: degrees=True is not for "from_rotvec" but for "as_euler".

Comment: degrees=True is for the output in degrees format

Comment: yeap sorry, wasn't paying close attention. It's a weird one I don't know enough maths to actually work out who's in the wrong